# SASS Importing In Wrong Order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm currently having an issue with SASS. When using the `@import` statement, it doesn't seem to acknowledge that I am importing a certain file before the others, causing some variables not to be declared. I am trying to make some simple changes to Bootstrap. The folder structure is as follows:

[image: folder structure]

My `app.scss` is the main entry point, which is as follows:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Droid+Sans+Mono|Droid+Serif'); //Basic fonts
@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap"; //Bootstrap
@import "bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome"; //Font Awesome

//Bootstrap style changes
@import "variables";

@import "components/alerts";
@import "components/buttons";
@import "components/dropdowns";
@import "components/forms";
@import "components/labels";
@import "components/navbars";
@import "components/pagination";
@import "components/panels";
@import "components/progress";
```

The issue is, the variables file isn't being imported either at all or before the other files are being loaded. This is a rather odd thing that I can't seem to figure out. I'd appreciate any help you can provide :)

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not describe the problem.  You have not shown your expected results nor the results you're getting.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to overwrite default Bootstrap variables, you need to import your file *before*  the actual Bootstrap variable partial. It's because all their variables have `!default` flag. It means that if a variable has already been assigned to, the next time you try to re-assign it, it will ignore that (unless it didn't have a variable assigned in the first place).

For example, let's say that in bootstrap's `_variables.scss` partial there is:

`$brand-primary: #555555 !default;`

...then in the next file that you import *after*, you assign something else to `$brand-primary` it will be ignored - even if you specify the `!default` flag again.

So that's why you need to overwrite variable *before* bootstrap does this.

e.g.

```
// custom-bootstap.scss contents:

// Core variables and mixins
@import "custom/bootstrap/variables"; // custom/overwritten variables
@import "bootstrap/variables";

@import "bootstrap/mixins";
...
```

and  inside `custom/bootstrap/variables`:

```
`$brand-primary: #000000!default;`
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap variables are declared with the `!default` flag, which means your file overriding those variables must be imported before the Boostrap files.

What does `!default` do? The assignment with this flag only takes effect if the variable wasn't declared before. That is to say, your override file *does* change those variables (unless you use the `!default` flag as well), but it does so *after* Boostrap had the chance to actually *consume* the variables. Example:

```
/*  bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss */
$alert-padding-y: .75rem !default;
$alert-padding-x: 1.25rem !default;

/*  bootstrap/scss/_alert.scss */
.alert {
  padding: $alert-padding-y $alert-padding-x; /* values are used */
}

/* your override */
$alert-padding-y: .5rem; /* values are changed, but a bit too late */
$alert-padding-x: 1rem;
```