# Modifying Bootswatch variables using Elixir

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, laravel-5, laravel-elixir, bootswatch

Using [this tutorial](https://github.com/stephanjusypiw/sassbootswatch) (on How to use Elixir and Laravel 5.* with Bootswatch) , I setup a Bootswatch stylesheet in my Laravel project with Elixir.

Everything works fine, the stylesheets are loaded and I have the Lumen style as wanted. But I don't get how to modify the Bootswatch variables ?

Here is my `app.scss`. Bootswatch files are loaded before I modify the variable :

```
@import "bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootswatch/lumen/variables";
@import "bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "bootswatch/lumen/bootswatch";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');

$brand-danger: purple;
```

But it doesn't works here.

When modifying this variable into `vendor/bower_components/bootswatch-sass/lumen/_variables.scss`, it works.

And here is the `gulpfile.js` :

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var bowerDirBootstrap = "vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/";
var bowerDirBootswatch = "vendor/bower_components/bootswatch-sass";
var bowerDirJquery = "vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/";

elixir(function(mix) {
     mix.sass('app.scss')
         // copy relevant files to the resources folder.  This is the css
         .copy(bowerDirBootstrap, 'resources/assets/sass/bootstrap')
         .copy(bowerDirBootswatch, 'resources/assets/sass/bootswatch')
         // this is the javascript
         .copy(bowerDirJquery + 'jquery.js', 'resources/assets/js/jquery.js')
         .copy(bowerDirBootstrap + 'javascripts/bootstrap.js',
         'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js')
         .version('css/app.css')

     mix.scripts([
             'js/jquery.js',
             'js/bootstrap.js'
         ],
         'public/js/app.js',
         'resources/assets'
     );
 });
```

To be honest I don't exactly understand the "copy" parts : when I delete them, everything still works as said before : modifying the variable in `_variable.scss` works, updating the variable in `app.scss` doesn't.

**Edit**

I've tried to put the variable everywhere and with / without the !default flag, nothing works.

```
$brand-danger: white !default;
@import "bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
$brand-danger: white !default;
@import "bootswatch/lumen/variables";
$brand-danger: white !default;
@import "bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap";
$brand-danger: white !default;
@import "bootswatch/lumen/bootswatch";
$brand-danger: white !default;
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100');
$brand-danger: white !default;
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');
$brand-danger: white !default;
```

Comment: You need to define your variables before you import the bootstrap / bootswatch scss

Comment: yup, have a look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964869/sass-importing-in-wrong-order/36968517#36968517

Comment: @Steve : It doesn't works any better

Comment: Thanks @kasperoo, as well it doesn't work neither.

Comment: I can override the Bootswatch variables putting my value before but only when I remove the Bootswatch variables...